# Redirect PHP echo to external file on eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, echo

I'm testing some php scripts on linux...

I know if i `run php script.php > file.txt` the result is going to be printed to file.txt, but i'm using eclipse pdt to run the scripts

how can i achieve the same behavion with eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured in the launch/run configuration:

1. ***Run > Run Configurations...***
2. In the tab ***Common*** check ***Output File*** and enter `file.txt`